# Do you have to write the type of a variable declared in a header file in a C++ file?

Tags: c++, header-files

I am trying to do some game programming. For this, I have to split my classes into different files. My header files look a bit like this:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include <someheader>

class Foo {
    private:
        int someInt;
    public:
        void setValue(int someValue);
};
```

So when I use `someInt` in my cpp file, can I just do this?

```
void Foo::setValue(int someValue) {
    someValue = someInt;
}
```

Or do I have to write `int someInt`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try what happens in each case? The function signature should be `void Foo::setValue(int someValue)` BTW.

Comment: @user0042 I can't really try it out as I have many files and I haven't setup my `main()` yet. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: _"I can't really try it out ..."_ You can always try out something small but complete besides the current project you're working on. You can do this even [online](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9cf875b0fac6f943).

Comment: Note: `someValue = someInt;` assigns `someInt` to a value parameter. The parameter won't be changed outside of that function.

Comment: I'm afraid user0042 didn't say it clear enough: You _must_ try this out in a self-standing small example. Otherwise, your larger project will never be successful if you are not sure about even such rather simple language details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
void Foo::setValue(int someValue) { someInt = someValue ; }
```

To make it as a set property

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46987518/edit) your existing answer instead of posting another one.